# Insert element into stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

is there a way to insert an element `T` into a `Stream<T>`?

```
    ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
    Foo foo = new Foo();

    Stream<Foo> stream = Stream.concat(foos.stream(), Stream.of(foo));
```

Is there another way? basically a kind of `foo.stream().add(foo)`... - of course add() doesn't exist. -

Comment: What is bothering you about the `concat` method?

Comment: @RealSkeptic well, it's a bit longer. Looks like an "workaround", and about performance, but that, I need to search more to be honest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's no other way to add elements to the given stream in standard Java Stream API. Some third-party libraries including my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) library provide [additional](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#append-T...-) convenient methods to do this:

```
Stream<Foo> stream = StreamEx.of(foos).append(foo);
```

Internally it uses the same `concat` method.

Similar method is available in [jOOL](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.5/org/jooq/lambda/Seq.html#concat-T-) library:

```
Stream<Foo> stream = Seq.seq(foos).concat(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `foos` don't exist. You can build a `Stream` with the `Stream.Builder` instead of an `ArrayList` like this:

```
Stream.Builder<Integer> builder = Stream.builder();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    builder.accept(i);
}
Stream<Integer> build = builder.add(50).build();
// ...
```

Comment: Good to know, that can be very useful.